# Running genymotion is causing some error

Tags: android

When i run genymotion i am getting the following errors, can someone please help me in rectifying this. My errors are:

```
W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0x9c10a700, error=EGL_SUCCESS
```

Comment: what is your emulator's API level

Comment: If your app doesn't crash you can safely ignore this error

Comment: API level is 22. Though the app is not crashing i am not getting the required output.